# Continuous map for closed points can't be extended to the whole projective space?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Given $X=\mathbb{P}^n_k$ for some algebraically closed field $k$ and some integer $n$. Let $Y$ be the set of closed points in $X$. Then it's said that a continuous map $f$ is defined on set $Y$ cannot be extended to a continuous map on $X$.

$Y$ is dense in $X$. Why can't we extend to the whole space? Hope someone could help. Thanks!

Comment: I don't have an example with $\Bbb P^n$ specifically (I'll post an answer if I can think of one), but it should not shock you that a map defined on a dense subset doesn't necessarily have an extension. Consider $\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ defined by $x\mapsto 1/x$ on the dense set $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$. This has no extension to a continuous map of the whole space, but it's defined on a dense subset.